# Deserialize a Json complex property into a string of Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is it possible to de-serialize a complex json object as a string. I am having trouble solving an issue similar to what is described below:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<int> MyList { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public string/object/variant MyProblem { get; set; }
}
```

Code used in the midddle-tier

```
model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(request.Model);
```

The problem is that MyProblem is actually a jagged array or it comes in multiple shapes by which I can't typify the structure to allow for de-serialization in a uniform manner. Is there a way that I can force `JsonConvert` to treat MyProblem as a string of Json instead of an object of Json?

**Moment of clarity:** It appears that if I define MyProblem as an object then the de-serialization will treat it as such and then `MyProblem.ToString()` will yield the json object as native string.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if I define MyProblem as an object then the de-serialization will treat it as such and then `MyProblem.ToString()` will yield the json object as native string.

Comment: Perfect, this was going to be a comment from me, glad you found something that is working.